# How to deploy tomcat application in Cluster environment

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat7, cluster-computing

I have 2 tomcat manager nodes those having each 5 instances.
If i deploy the application in 2 manager nodes it should be reflect in to the remaining instances also.
for that i tried many links.But i am unable to do.